Magnetic field of a solenoid with linear dielectric from a geometric series
I have seen a solution to the problem of computing the electric field $E$ of a linear dielectric inside a perfect capacitor by using a geometric series that avoids using the displacement $D$. This is done in this question, for example.
It goes like by successive approximations, like this. If the charge density is $\sigma_0$, it produces a field $E_0=\sigma_0/\epsilon_0$. This leads to an initial polarization $P_0=\chi_e E_0$ and a new charge density $\sigma_1=-P_0=-\chi_e E_0$. Now we do another round. The charge density $\sigma_1$ produces a field $E_1=\sigma_1/\epsilon_0$, which leads to $P_1=\chi_e E_1$ and a new charge density $\sigma_2=-P_1=(-\chi_e)^2 E_0$. A geometric series ensues and we have the final field as $E=E_0/(1+\chi_e)$.
I would like to know if there is an analogous magnetic version. Say we have a perfect solenoid with current $I_0$ and we insert a linear medium inside. Can we compute the final magnetic field by means of a geometric series?

I will attempt to answer my own question, but I am not quite convinced by this answer.
An initial current $I_0$ produces a field $B_0=\mu_0 n I_0$, which leads to an initial magnetization of $M_0=\chi_m B_0/\mu_0$. This magnetization corresponds to a new current $nI_1=M_0$, which leads to a new field, $B_1=\mu_0 M_0= \chi_m B_0$. Going around one more time, we have $M_1=\chi_m B_1/\mu_0$, $nI_2=M_1$ and $B_2=\chi_m^2 B_0$.
So the final answer would be
$$B=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \chi_m^n B_0=\frac{B_0}{(1-\chi_m)}.$$
Is this correct?
